# Comprobar columna de otra tabla antes de insertar un registro en otra tabla distinta

Tags: mysql

buenas noches. Estoy creando una base de datos sobre alquiler de coches bastante simple en la que tengo tres tablas: cliente, coche y alquiler.

En la tabla coche hay una columna llamada "alquilado" en la que si el coche está alquilado, hay un 1, y en caso contrario, un 0. 
Bien, pues yo quiero comprobar antes de insertar en la tabla alquiler un registro si el coche con matrícula "X" tiene en esa columna un 1 o un 0, y si es un 1, no dejar insertar.

El problema viene a la hora de comprobar eso... Imagino que se hará con una función, y después un constraint dependiendo del valor que devuelva la función, o algo así... Pero no consigo ver cómo hacerlo, si me podéis echar un cable os lo agradecería muchísimo.

Un saludo, buenas noches, y muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Me parece que tienes mal planteada tu estrctura al menos en la tabla coche pues no hay razón lógico que al registrar uno nuevo le coloques si está o no alquilado ya que ese no es un atributo propio del vehículo, caso contrario tal otra tabla que hablé sobre el registro del alquiler de vehículos y ahí almacenes la foránea del coche y la foránea de quién lo renta

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que tus tablas son las siguientes o similares:

```
Coches (matricula, marca, modelo, ...)
   CP-> matrícula
Clientes (dni, nombre, direccion, ...)
   CP-> dni
Alquileres (coche, cliente, fecha, ...)
   CP-> coche, cliente
   CAj-> coche -> Coches(matricula)
   CAj-> cliente -> Clientes(dni)
```

En ese caso para saber si un coche está alquilado debes comprobar si en la tabla Alquileres existe un registro con el coche en cuestión.
En ese caso te basta con indicar que en la tabla Alquileres el campo coche es único. Así si se intenta insertar un coche que ya existe saltará dicha restricción.

Ahora bien si la tabla de Alquileres te sirve como histórico la solución de arriba no te sirve y en ese caso lo que deberás de hacer es un trigger que actúe tras insertar en la tabla Alquileres:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_alquiler AFTER INSERT ON Alquileres
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET @alquilado = (SELECT alquilado FROM Coches WHERE matricula=NEW.coche)
    IF @alquilado == 1 THEN
        DELETE FROM Alquileres WHERE coche=NEW.coche AND cliente=NEW.cliente
    END IF;
END;//
```

Comment: Buenos días Alex. Muchas gracias por la ayuda. La cuestión es esa, que mi idea era que la tabla alquileres sirviese de histórico, pero claro, veo que puede ser un problema, porque a la hora de eliminar un coche, al ser matrícula fk, no podría. Así que creo que lo adecuado es crear una tabla registros en la que cada vez que se registre un alquiler, se copie allí la matrícula y el nombre de la persona y el coche que se alquila. ¿Sería mejor de esa forma, verdad?

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieras el diagrama ER para poder aconsejarte sobre la mejor opción.